# Write to local database but read from remote database/mysql-server

Tags: php, mysql

So at work we have the following problem: We develop a php application that runs on multiple servers for a number of different clients. When we a problem or bug occurs on a clients application, we often have to download a dump of the whole database and import it locally to our machines to try and replicate the problem and fix it.
My idea is the following: Seperate the mysql read and write commands, so the application only reads from the remote database (the clients db) and writes to either our local database or preferrably, into the void. We do not want to implement such a functionality for our application, because it would be a very big change to the core of our application.
So my question is if there is any way to achive my goal? Any suggestions?

Comment: How would this be a very big change? You just to need to open an extra connection to the local `mysql` instance and replace the connection u'r using in the code when doing a write

Comment: it's difficult to make suggestions without knowing anything about your architecture.  I would echo @DarkBee and say that this seems like a couple of hours work (to account for testing) assuming you're injecting your connection object.  I don't think there'a a solution that would be possible without changing your application though, you can't magically intercept the connection object

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only valid way is to change the architecture of our application.